# Dynamixel Controller for MX28AT

Tags: ros, dynamixel, ros-indigo, dynamixel-motor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS, I want to control Dynamixel motor MX28AT with ROS. Which controller should i use? and how to use it? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232215/dynamixel-controller-for-mx28at/) by [calvintanct](https://answers.ros.org/users/26515/calvintanct/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can choose another package such as [Dynamixel-workbench](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/dynamixel-workbench)
This is official package for DYNAMIXEL from ROBOTIS.

If you want to get any information, please visit its [emanual](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_workbench/)

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0